# iOS String picker default selection fail

Tags: codenameone

I've faced a bug last week on a native iOS picker.
I'm using it to select a model for some documents, and when I click the picker, the first entry is selected. But if I click on the OK button, my picker show that nothing is selected.

I need to scroll the picker content a bit to select the first element. Is it a normal iOS behavior or must I set something to achieve the autoselection of the first element when the ok button is pressed ?

Comment: That might be a regression. Please file an issue with exact iOS version you are using and device type (iPad/iPhone etc.)

Comment: Issue filed on Github.

Comment: Assigned it https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the lightweight mode with the last CN1 update solve the problem on iOS.